# insert and update escape charcter, simple and double quotes in the same time in a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, insert-update, mysql-real-escape-string, double-quotes

I am concerned about inserting text in a MySQl table w.
I have to insert/update text that contains characters such as / " and '

The escape character / could be inserted only if  the NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES SQL mode is enabled. wich interfere with the characters " and ' see this link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-literals.html#character-escape-sequences

If anyone can explain to is in earth the mysql_real_escape_string() I don't came to understated

I would like to find a pure mysql solution 
I am not using php. What I am trying to do here is to "simulate " Content Management System: I am about to write a C# coded solution that manage the content in its different forms(article, category ,tag, etc..) and generate .html files, the MySQl database is local in my computer next i will upload the .html files to the server.

I did this to ensure that all my html pages are html valid and because I don't trust any existent solutions (not only when it concerns coding but in life in general)

Please help

Answer (score 0):

each php db connection extension (**mysql, mysqli, pdo**) has a special way to safe query against sql injections, when you are using mysql extension, it's strongly recommended to use `mysql_real_escape_string()` function to make safe all variables used in query, it's most widely used function. i think there isn't any pure solution (when you are using mysql extension in php).
from php.net:

> mysql_real_escape_string()-Escapes special characters in the
>   unescaped_string, taking into account the current character set of the
>   connection so that **it is safe to place it in a mysql_query()**.

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string() has nothing to do with injections. It does not make any characters "safe". It shouldn't be used on "all variables". It is not "strongly recommended", as it's just a string formatting facility: so, it is not "recommended" but ought to be used to format strings, yet shouldn't be used on anything else

Comment: so tell me how you make safe vars when using mysql extension?  is there another way to do that??

Comment: I am not using php. What I am trying to do here is to "simulate " Content Management System: I am about to write a C# coded solution that manage the content in its different forms(article, category ,tag, etc..) and generate .html files, the MySQl database is local in my computer next i will upload the .html files to the server. I did this to ensure that all my html pages are html valid and because I don't trust any existent solutions (not only when it concerns coding but in life in general)

Answer (score -1):

Whatever string data can be inserted into SQL query, if formatted according to 2 rules

- it is enclosed in quotes (preferably single ones)
- it is passed through mysql_real_escape_string()

if both rules followed, there would be not a single problem with whatever characters, either slashes, quotes or anything.

According to your question, `/` has no special meaning in MySQL. It's `\` that is escape character. It can be escaped by another backslash as well.

```
$str = 'slashes \ quotes \' or whatever " else symbols';
var_dump($str);
$str = mysql_real_escape_string($str);
$sql = "INSERT INTO table SET str='$str'";
```

Comment: Yes I am sorry about the escape character it's \ and not /  thanks

Comment: Would you please be more specific about how to implement your solution, because I am not a mysql guru.Please note that I am not using php or similar solution just MySQL .Thanks